# Specify rule in grammar for embedded DSL, if compiler can't verify it?

Tags: java, grammar, dsl

Is it common to define a rule in a grammar for an embedded DSL, even if the compiler can not validate the correctness of the given code? The rule I'm talking about is one that applies at runtime.

Here's an example:

I have a function that reads arbitrary classes and searches them for methods marked with a specific [annotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_annotation). In addition the methods must have a `boolean` return type. I haven't found a way to define the annotation class to be only valid on methods with specific return types, so I check it at runtime, and raise an error if the method does not return `boolean`.

Now I want to specify a grammar for the internal/embedded DSL given by the tool. So basically a class with an annotated method with return type `int` is not valid.

So should the grammar contain a rule, forbidding other return types than `boolean`, or not?

Papers and/or articles on the topic would be helpful, too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A *grammar* for an *internal* DSL?  That doesn't make sense.  Internal DSLs are are set of APIs that are specific to the problem; they have signatures but not a grammar.   Are you thinking that you want to define a standalone grammar for these?  Or that you want to extend the Java grammar itself?

Comment: As I understand the definition, _embedded/internal_ DSL's can also be subsets of the host programming language. So wouldn't that the part of the grammar describing the subset for the DSL be a valid grammar for the _embedded/internal_ DSL?

Comment: Your "embedded"  DSL must necessarily follow the syntax of the host language.   Don't confuse "language" (set of valid strings) with "grammar" (a description of the structure of those string, that doesn't necessarily accept exactly the language.  Whatever grammar was used to parse the language before you "added" the embedded DSL, still parses the language with the added DSL.   But the grammar doesn't necessarily accept *only* valid language strings; it practice, it must accept *more* than all valid language strings because the parser/grammar combination cannot eliminate semantic errors.

Comment: What this means in practice is the constraints introduced by your DSL are surely outside the scope of the grammar.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it common to define a rule in a grammar for an embedded DSL, even if the compiler can not validate the correctness of the given code? The rule I'm talking about is one that applies at runtime.

I think you're referring to "the compiler" for code written in your DSL -- i.e. a program that evaluates the DSL code and transforms it to some other representation -- as opposed to a Java compiler with which you are building that program.  In that case, this is a question of semantics, in more ways than one.

In the first place, if a compiler for your DSL cannot validate your rule then by definition, it is not a grammar rule.  In that sense, the answer to your question is trivially "no" -- not only is what you describe not common, it doesn't even make sense.

On the other hand, you seem to be describing a *semantic* rule of your language, and there's nothing at all wrong or uncommon with a language having such rules.  Most languages of any complexity do.  I do not speak to your specific example, however, because it seems largely a matter of opinion, which is off-topic here.

Comment: In this case _the compiler_ is the java compiler. It is an embedded/internal DSL, so it is defined in the same language, in this case Java. I thought the same as you described in the _in the first place_ paragraph, but I wasn't sure.

Answer (score 1):

It is common for language specifications to contain text (with varying degrees of formality) which constrains correct programs in ways that go beyond the possibilities of syntactic analysis. You don't have to look very far for examples; the C, C++ and ECMAScript standards are full of them.

But if you cannot verify a constraint at compile-time, it is clearly impossible to include the constraint in the *grammar*. Even constraints which can theoretically be detected at compile-time can be difficult to include in a formal context-free grammar (requiring variable declaration before use, for example, or more generally insisting on correct typing). Other formalisms exist, but they are not really grammatical.

Comment: I'll agree that the conventional context free grammars are the mainstream approach.  For context free grammars, yes, of course; you only get the syntax constraints.  For more sophisticated specification techniques (e.g., van Wingarden two-level grammars, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Wijngaarden_grammar or Quinn Jackson's Meta-S, which are both Turing capable, you can do this).

Comment: Sure, but I doubt whether OP really wants to implement a VW parser. Maybe I'm projecting :-). I'll try to rewrite more precisely.

Comment: I came up with an _embedded DSL_ for my masters thesis and my Prof asked, if there exists a formal (I suppose context-free, since Java has a context-free grammar as far as I know) grammar defining it. That was when my question came up, since a writing a grammar, if it is not common/possible/... to describe runtime behaviour it would be a simple copy-paste of the part of the Java grammar that defines the subset I'm using.